# renewcommand \cite[99]{Turing} vs. \cite{Turing}

Tags: macros, biblatex

I use \cite commands  both as `\cite[99]{Turing}` and `\cite{Turing}`.

I wish to redefine the command as it follows:

```
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[2]{[\oldcite[#1]{#2}]}
```

but then if I try just to use `\cite{Turing}`, I get an error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{prova}
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[2]{[\oldcite[#1]{#2}]}
\begin{document}
text
\cite{99}{Turing} % Ok, but I would like to type \cite[99]{Turing} 
\cite{Turing} 
%error ! Paragraph ended before \blx@xsanitizeafter was complete.
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\cite}[2]{...}` defines `\cite` to have _two_ arguments. You should also use `\cite{99}{Turing}` after the redefinition.

Comment: do I really need `letltxmacro`?

Comment: If `\cite{99}{Turing}` works apparently not. `\cite{Turing}` _must_ go wrong as it needs a second argument the way you defined it. It's not really clear to me what you want to achieve, though...

Comment: I think you want `\renewcommand{\cite}[2][]{[\oldcite[#1]{#2}]}` (notice the second optional argument to `\renewcommand`). I believe with `biblatex` there are better ways to get square brackets around the citation.

Comment: YES, it works! great thks.

Answer (score 3):

The neatest solution is to use the rich facilities `biblatex` provides to deal with exactly this problem.
The relevant command is `\DeclareCiteCommand` [p. 131 of the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

We define a new citation command `\brackcite` based on the definition of `\parencite`.
Just add the code snippets to your preamble.

The following code should work for all standard `biblatex` styles.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\brackcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

In case this does not work properly - other styles like `biblatex-philosophy` and `biblatex-apa` use different macros -, find the definition of `\parencite` for that style (it should be in the `.cbx` file) copy its definition to your preamble, rename it to `\brackcite` and modify the definition from `\mkbibparens` to `\mkbibbrackets`.

To define the starred version provided by `authortitle` and `authoryear`, we do exactly the same

```
\DeclareCiteCommand*{\brackcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citetitle}}% or \usebibmacro{citeyear} for authoryear
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

This command is not defined by all styles, just check your style's `.cbx` and copy and modify the definition as above.

You can then use `\brackcite` just like any other `\*cite` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\brackcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

% use only for styles that support this (standard authordate and authortitle styles do)
% replace \usebibmacro{citetitle} by \usebibmacro{citeyear} for authoryear
\DeclareCiteCommand*{\brackcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citetitle}}% change this to \usebibmacro{citeyear} for authoryear
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \verb|\cite{herrmann}| & \cite{herrmann}\\
  \verb|\parencite{herrmann}| & \parencite{herrmann}\\
  \verb|\brackcite{herrmann}| & \brackcite{herrmann}\\
  \verb|\cite[99]{herrmann}| & \cite[99]{herrmann}\\
  \verb|\parencite[99]{herrmann}| & \parencite[99]{herrmann}\\
  \verb|\brackcite[99]{herrmann}| & \brackcite[99]{herrmann}\\
  \verb|\cite[see][99]{herrmann}| & \cite[99][see]{herrmann}\\
  \verb|\parencite[see][99]{herrmann}| & \parencite[see][99]{herrmann}\\
  \verb|\brackcite[see][99]{herrmann}| & \brackcite[see][99]{herrmann}\\
\end{tabular}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image]