# Is there a recommended way to replace \cite with \parencite?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am currently porting a large document to use biblatex-apa. Everything is finally getting into place, but I've now realized that to get correct APA citations I should use `\parencite` instead of `\cite`.

I really don't want to replace the citations throughout the entire document, especially when every other day they will change the reference manager backend.

Is there an easy way to simply reinterpret `\cite` with `\parencite` everywhere in the document?

Comment: You could `\let\cite\parencite`, but I'm not too fond of that. Why don't you just search and replace `\cite` and  `\parencite` in your editor? That should be a thing of 30 secs tops in most modern editors. And it can easily be undone by the opposite replacement.

Comment: `\let\cite\parencite` is great. Honestly, the reason is this is a version controlled document that will be parsed and reinterpreted by multiple backends (i.e. both biber and bibtex) on a regular basis. There is a big desire in this case to have a single cite command. The document is quite big.

Comment: Mhhh, OK, maybe then the `\autocite` thing is more relevant than I thought.

Comment: Just curious, what does the backend have to do with the choice of `\cite` or `\parencite`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. My question exactly ;-) why should it? Unfortunately a citation with biblatex-apa does not place the required parenthesis surrounding the citation, for some reason. I have searched quite extensively and the best suggestion I got was to use `\parencite`.

Comment: So why not find&replace all `\cite` to `\parencite`? And what does that have to do with `bibtex` vs. `biber`? Do you get the correct citations with one, but not the other?

Comment: `\cite` produces correct citations using `apacite`+`bibtex`. `\parencite` is required to produce the same citation format with `biblatex-apa`+`biber`. If the solution is going to be find and replace anyway, I still prefer the redefinition answer, since at least it gets written somewhere in the preamble file and doesn't exist only in a human user's head. You could batch script, but then again isn't that exactly the same as simply redefining the command in the preamble? Seems like a lot of pain for no gain.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were just changing the backend of `biblatex` (it can be used with `bibtex` as well), not replacing `biblatex` altogether.

Comment: This is probably because `biblatex` has slightly more rigid system when it comes to naming the cite commands. `\cite` normally does not have brackets (even if the style guide requires this for 'normal' citations), `\parencite` always has (some kind) of brackets. BibTeX styles might not be that rigid here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *could*

```
\let\cite\parencite
```

but I'm not too fond of that, in fact I cringe every time I have to see this.
Normally `\let`ting around commands willy-nilly might have (unforeseeable, bad) consequences, but it is quite unlikely that you break things if you use `biblatex`.

With `biblatex` there is the high-level command `\autocite` that you can use. Then you can easily configure `biblatex` to use normal `\cite`, brackets with `\parencite` or footnotes with `\footcite` for `\autocite`. (Mildly related: [Universal `\cite` commands or defining new cite commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158480/35864))

In most modern editors it will take 30 seconds tops to do a 'search and replace' for `\cite` vs. `\parencite`. That can of course easily be undone by the opposite replacement.

Comment: There was a similar question on `comp.text.tex` years ago with virtually the same answer (minus the 'I don't like this' part): https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/efmAcnGQ1CU/0JC7z62r1BMJ