# problems with bst file

Tags: bibliographies

I have a .tex file created with a .bib file. Now, I have to incorporate a .bst file into my latex file to follow the journal’s instructions.

I already have created the .bst file using latex makebst but have trouble in incorporanting this .bst file into my original latex file .

FILE WITHOUT .BST FILE

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article} 

**\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=authoryear-comp,bibstyle=authortitle,maxcitenames=2,sorting=nyt,maxbibnames=9]{biblatex}** 

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\hl[1]{

  \bgroup

  \hskip0pt\color{red!80!black}

  #1

  \egroup

}

\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{epsfig} 

\usepackage{amsmath} 

\usepackage{amssymb} 

\usepackage{setspace} 

\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage[section] {placeins} 

\usepackage{lscape} 

\usepackage{threeparttable} 

\usepackage{appendix} 

\usepackage{longtable} 

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}[date] 

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\usepackage[tablename=TABLE]{caption} 
\usepackage[figurename=FIGURE]{caption}

\usepackage[labelsep=none]{caption} 

\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{up}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}} 

\captionsetup[table]{ 

    labelsep=newline,

}

\captionsetup[figure]{ 

    labelsep=newline,

}



\setlength{\textwidth}{6in} 

\setlength{\textheight}{8.5in} 

\setlength{\topmargin}{.25in} 

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.25in} 

\setlength{\footskip}{0.00in} 

\setlength{\headheight}{0.00in} 

\setlength{\headsep}{0.5in} 

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\bunderline}[2][4]{\underline{#2\mkern-#1mu}\mkern#1mu}

\newcommand{\boverline}[2][4]{\overline{#2\mkern-#1mu}\mkern#1mu}

\newcommand{\nunder}[2][5]{\mathrlap{\mkern\the\numexpr#1/2mu\relax\underline{\phantom{\mathrm{#2}\mkern-#1mu}}}#2}

\newcommand{\nunderline}[2][4]{

\ensuremath{\mathrlap{\mkern#1mu\underline{\phantom{\mathrm{#2}\mkern-#1mu}}}}#2}

**\addbibresource{biblio_teachers.bib}**

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}

\onehalfspacing 

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\pagestyle{myheadings}



\begin{center}

{\Large \textbf{title}}\\

\bigskip

{\normalsize author}\footnote{Contact information}\\

\textit{\small place} \\

\bigskip

{\normalsize \hl{date}}

\end{center}



\begin{spacing}{0.9}

\begin{list}{}{\leftmargin=2.5em \rightmargin=2.5em}

\onehalfspacing

\item

{\footnotesize\textbf{Abstract.-}

.....bla bla bla ...

\newline {\small \textbf{JEL Classification:} J13, J44, J45, C61.}

\end{list}

\end{spacing}



\setcounter{footnote}{0}\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}

\newpage \pagenumbering{arabic}

\newgeometry{top=0.8in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in} 

...

bla bla bla

....

\section*{REFERENCES}

\printbibliography[heading=none]



\end{document}
```

FILE WITH .BST FILE

```
\documentclass{article}

**\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}**

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\hl[1]{

  \bgroup

  \hskip0pt\color{red!80!black}

  #1

  \egroup

}

\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{epsfig} 

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage[section] {placeins}

\usepackage{lscape} 

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{appendix} 

\usepackage{longtable} 

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}[date] 

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\usepackage[tablename=TABLE]{caption}

\usepackage[figurename=FIGURE]{caption}

\usepackage[labelsep=none]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{up}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}} 

\captionsetup[table]{

    labelsep=newline,

}

\captionsetup[figure]{ 

    labelsep=newline,

}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6in} 

\setlength{\textheight}{8.5in} 

\setlength{\topmargin}{.25in} 

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.25in} 

\setlength{\footskip}{0.00in} 

\setlength{\headheight}{0.00in} 

\setlength{\headsep}{0.5in}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry} 

\newcommand{\bunderline}[2][4]{\underline{#2\mkern-#1mu}\mkern#1mu}

\newcommand{\boverline}[2][4]{\overline{#2\mkern-#1mu}\mkern#1mu}

\newcommand{\nunder}[2][5]{\mathrlap{\mkern\the\numexpr#1/2mu\relax\underline{\phantom{\mathrm{#2}\mkern-#1mu}}}#2}

\newcommand{\nunderline}[2][4]{

\ensuremath{\mathrlap{\mkern#1mu\underline{\phantom{\mathrm{#2}\mkern-#1mu}}}}#2}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}

\onehalfspacing 

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}

\thispagestyle{empty} 

\pagestyle{myheadings}



\begin{center}

{\Large \textbf{title}}\\

\bigskip



{\normalsize author}\footnote{Contact information}\\

\textit{\small place} \\

\bigskip

{\normalsize \hl{date}}

\end{center}

\begin{spacing}{0.9}

\begin{list}{}{\leftmargin=2.5em \rightmargin=2.5em}

\onehalfspacing

\item

{\footnotesize\textbf{Abstract.-}

... bla bla bla...


\newline {\small \textbf{JEL Classification:} J13, J44, J45, C61.}

\end{list}

\end{spacing}

\setcounter{footnote}{0}\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}

\newpage \pagenumbering{arabic}

\newgeometry{top=0.8in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in} 

...

bla bla bla

....

**\bibliographystyle{PVbibsty} 
\bibliography{biblio_teachers}**

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since `biblatex` and `.bst` files are incompatible it makes a lot of sense that you would switch to `natbib`. What problem exactly are you having with the posted code? It looks like it should work. (I say that not having tested it, because the code is not compilable for us: It is not an example document in the sense of an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)

Comment: My problem is that when I use the bib package I get in my references all the citations not only \cite but \textcite \parencite ... etc but using the bst file I got less references specifically the ones linked to the command \cite I wonder if this problem of the bst or my maintex.

Comment: If you use `natbib` (which may or may not work with the specific `.bst` style) you can use `\citep` and `\citet` (as replacements for `\parencite` and `\textcite`). No matter what you do, you will not be able to use `biblatex` with a `.bst` style.

Comment: Thanks for your help your tip was really useful.  Do you know where can I find a list of other kind of replacements, for example: for autocite, citeauthor, etc ?

Comment: There is no `\autocite` replacement, but you would probably choose `\citep` for that anyway. `\citeauthor` should also work with `natbib`. Not all `biblatex` commands have `natbib` equivalents. Maybe http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natnotes.pdf can help you.

Comment: Great!, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.bst` files are intended for use with BibTeX and can't be used with the `biblatex` package, because `biblatex` uses a completely different way to produce citations and bibliographies than BibTeX.

So if you have a `.bst` file you must use, you can't use `biblatex`.

If you are lucky, though, your `.bst` file is compatible with `natbib`. In that case you can at least use the advanced citation commands that `natbib` provides. That won't give you all the things you could do with `biblatex`, but it may be enough for many basic needs - especially for simpler numeric citations. Some macros will have different names and so you will probably have to do some search-and-replace. Note that there may well be subtle and not so subtle differences between `biblatex` and `natbib` in terms of their citation commands.

Even though `natbib` knows `\cite` (for compatibility reasons), it should be replaced by `\citep` or `\citet`. Other `biblatex` commands and their `natbib` counterparts include

- `\parencite` -> `\citep`
- `\textcite` -> `\citet`
- `\citeauthor` -> `\citeauthor`
- `\citeyear`/`\citedate` -> `\citeyear`

`natbib` has no `\autocite`, but you may be able to just use `\citep` instead.

You can have a look at [the `natbib` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf) or [this handy reference sheet](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natnotes.pdf) for more info on `natbib`'s commands.

Mildly related: [Universal `\cite` commands or defining new cite commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158480/35864)